# working with big owl files

Tags: java, ontology, owl-api, dlquery

Im working on a project where my plan is to get the topic name(hierarchy in the tree given a word) for eg:given stack i need to get Datastructures, given chemotherapy is should be gettig somethig like chemistry etc.., i Have used DL query tab on some ontology which is very big and i don't get find a specific ontology .owl file where i can get the higher level topic name.
i wrote the DL query tab program which runs out of heap space given a query.problems are

- The ontology i have contains many words but i fail to retrieve the hierarchy(superclass,subclass),
- the ontology asks for manchester syntax while i have a simple word--how can i map the word to the class in an ontology
- IS there a way we can find the topic name like the example given a set of words using some owl ontology

Comment: Which ontologies are you using? How big are they actually?
The words that you see in the ontology, are they class names or labels? For class names, you just type them in the dl query tab, but for labels the syntax is more complex.

Answer (score 0):

For an OutOfMemory error, use -Xmx to increase the amount of heap memory available.
For example, `-Xmx2000M` will give two gigabytes of memory to Protege.

You are probably starting Protege from a script; if you edit it, you'll find the option, with a smaller number, already there. You can edit that file to increase the amount.